# how to put arguments into contextual filters

Tags: 7, views

In this post http://drupal.org/node/228959 says that i need to add an code to the argument of view2,

I add a contextual filter in views 3, but where is the spot to place the following code?

```
if (arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    return array(arg(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a comment in that article [down below](http://drupal.org/node/228959#comment-4591334) with a code to import for D7 and Views 3.

If you import that code into your Views 3 and then study the **Contextual Filters** and the **Relationships** you should get a good idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: i see, so there ain't a easier way to do it